Solana program created by anchor consumes too many CUs without any action
I have developed solana program using anchor, and it works well so far.
But due to its large CU, tx doesn't land sometimes, so I tried to optimize CU.
I've implemented many approaches and CU has been reduced a little.
Nevertheless, CU is still high, and I removed all lines in function, but it also consumed nearly the same CUs.
I thought it is due to anchor's default behavior to deserialize/parse accounts, PDAs, etc.
    pub fn FuncName(
        ctx: Context<FuncStruct>,
        param1: u8,
        param2: bool,
        param3: u8,
        param4: String
    ) -> Result<()> {
       // I removed all lines of codes here.
    }

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct FuncStruct<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = ["XXXX".as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pda: Account<'info, MyPdaAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    ...
    ...
    // Many accounts here
}


I know that in FuncStruct there are many accounts, which results in consuming CU despite of zero line of code.
But is there any solution to make anchor to consume least CU in parsing/deserializing accounts?
It is consuming about 70000 CU basically without any codes in function.

Typically for Anchor programs, the approach is to use ZeroCopy if you want more efficient deserialization. There's some info about it at https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/space.html?highlight=zero#space-reference. Alternatively, you could avoid using Anchor, but that requires you to perform checks and deserialization on your accounts by hand.
